# The Picard-Lindelöf theorem on Wikipedia

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

On the Wikipedia entry of Picard-Lindelöf theorem for the local existence and uniqueness of ODE's, there is a section on the optimization of the solution's interval.

There is a lemma used in this section which says
$$
  || \Gamma^m \varphi_1 - \Gamma^m \varphi_2 || \leq \dfrac{L^m \alpha^m}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||
$$
Please see the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for the definition of symbols above.

I can not get the $m!$ term in the denominator and believe that the lemma is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: There is also a proof given in the section you cite. Have you read it? Where do you disagree?

Comment: m! term should not appear in the denominator.

Comment: I think one should replace the claim
$$
\|\Gamma^m \phi_1 - \Gamma^m \phi_2 \| \le \frac{ L^m \alpha^m}{m!}\|\phi_1-\phi_2\|
$$
by 
$$
\|\Gamma^m \phi_1(s) - \Gamma^m \phi_2(s) \| \le \frac{ L^m}{m!}(s-t_0)^m\|\phi_1-\phi_2\| \quad \forall s\in(t_0,t_0+a).
$$
Very sloppy proof there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's prove this:
$$
|| \Gamma^{m} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma^{m} \varphi_2(t) || \leq \dfrac{L^{m} |t-t_0|^{m}}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||, \ \forall t \in I_a
$$

With $m = 1$, is trivial. If the induction hypothesis is:

$$|| \Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(t) || \leq \dfrac{L^{m-1} |t-t_0|^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||, \ \forall t \in I_a
$$

Then $\forall t \in I_a$:

\begin{align}
|| \Gamma^{m} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma^{m} \varphi_2(t) || = \left|\left| \Gamma\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma \Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(t) \right|\right|    &=    \left|\left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \ f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(s) \right) - f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(s) \right) ds \ \right|\right| \\
&\leq \left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \left|\left| \ f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(s) \right) - f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(s) \right) \right|\right| ds \right|
\end{align}
But $f$ is Lipschitz in $I_a \times B_b$ in the second variable with $L$ as Lipschitz constant. Then:

\begin{align}
\left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \left|\left| \ f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(s) \right) - f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(s) \right) \right|\right| ds \right|
&\leq
L \left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \left|\left| \ \Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(s) - \Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(s) \right|\right| ds \right|   \\
\end{align}

And by induction hypothesis:

\begin{align}
\left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \left|\left| \ f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_1(s) \right) - f\left(s,\Gamma^{m-1} \varphi_2(s) \right) \right|\right| ds \right|
&\leq
L \left| \int_{t_0}^{t} \dfrac{L^{m-1} |s-t_0|^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 || \ ds \right|   \\
&\leq
\dfrac{L^m}{(m-1)!} \left| \int_{t_0}^{t} |s-t_0|^{m-1} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 || \ ds \right|   \\
&\leq
\frac{L^m|t-t_0|^m}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||   \\
\end{align}
Then the previous proposition is right, now:
\begin{align}
|| \Gamma^{m} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma^{m} \varphi_2(t) || \leq \dfrac{L^{m} |t-t_0|^{m}}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 || \leq \dfrac{L^{m} a^{m}}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||, \ \forall t \in I_a
\end{align}
Then:
\begin{align}
\textrm{sup} \left\{ || \Gamma^{m} \varphi_1(t) - \Gamma^{m} \varphi_2(t) || : t \in I_a \right\} &\leq \dfrac{L^{m} a^{m}}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||, \ \forall t \in I_a     \\
|| \Gamma^{m} \varphi_1 - \Gamma^{m} \varphi_2 || &\leq \dfrac{L^{m} a^{m}}{m!} ||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2 ||
\end{align}

Comment: very good answer thanks